# Nagios config nesting - including config to config

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm using icinga/nagios to monitor a huge bunch of servers and clients. So I wrote some scripts to dynamically generate my host configs. 
No I'm not so really glad with this big construct because sometimes I want to have on or two extra service checks on a certain server. 
In this case I can create a "manual" config but I also want all the 20 normal checks....

Now I wonder if there is a possibility  to add a "include" directive to a config? Like:

`include "../manual/configs/hostname.cfg"`

So I could add an extra file to every dynamically created config and fill there some extra checks if not I leaf it blank.

Thanks for help
Regards Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Nagios/Icinga 1.x but Icinga 2.x